# Android: proper use of ndk for newbie?

Tags: java, android, c++, bitmap, android-ndk

1. According to [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html) there are a lot of sensors types that available via NDK, but not GPS? Am I right and GPS accessible only via JNI?
2. Is it possible to process sensor events in background with active Java Activity?
   I want to handle accelerometer and gyroscope events in native code and two times per second show it in window (java activity). 
   But if I have NativeActivity to handle sensor events, it should be on foreground, so I can not show result of processing without stopping processing, if I use java activity to show result?
3. How handle bitmaps? I have native library to create bitmap with map,
   then I want to draw a lot of objects over this bitmap with lot of calls for
   geographical coordinates<->screen coordinates. At first I thought to implement
   this on native side and use Java only to draw bitmap in Activity,
   but looks like NDK have no 2D drawing stuff, only to get bitmap from java,
   and put it back to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NDK gives access to the same set of sensors as Java framework does. And yes, there is no GPS, moreover it is not a sensor in common sense.
2. Sensor event handling doesn't depend on `Activity` lifecycle, so you can just create dedicated `ASensorEventQueue` and obtain results via your `ALooper_callbackFunc`.
3. NDK gives only ability to test `Bitmap`'s size, pixel format and to get access to pixel buffer which you can freely modify. (The last one is for mutable bitmaps only). There is no 2D drawing API. You should use third-party software for such purpose. Bytheway you can try OpenGL for your drawing. It requires no `Bitmap` and only `ANativeWindow`.

Comment: Thanks, about **3**. I have to draw text a lot (captions for objects), so I need ttf font, library for rendering font and so on, I hoped that I can reuse already existing stuff from android platform.

Comment: You can use only Java API, even via JNI. But it is painful and hard to maintain. So, better to look for third-party drawing lib.